# Fabricjs svg parsing error

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

guys, i've got a very mysterious problem here.

I've got an svg `<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='263.342' height='132.29' viewBox='0 0 263.342 132.29'><path fill='#FFC55D' d='M148.718 39.53S152.442 0 199.442 0v57.604l-26.236-18.628-16.908 18.628-.467 42.678s-.99 18.658-20.113 18.658'/><path fill='#FEDBC8' d='M63.44 132.29c-44 0-46.084-38.09-45.903-44.62-1.45 0-11.837-1.268-11.837-9.974 0-13.785 11.74-11.97 11.74-11.97V55.567l-.644-24.077H63.44v100.8zM63.44 132.29c43 0 45.76-38.09 45.58-44.62 1.45 0 11.5-1.268 11.5-9.974 0-13.785-12.08-11.97-12.08-11.97V55.567l.995-24.077H63.44v100.8z'/><path fill='#1CA97E' d='M46.18 70.078c0 3.405-2.76 6.167-6.167 6.167-3.406 0-6.167-2.762-6.167-6.167 0-3.406 2.76-6.167 6.167-6.167 3.406 0 6.167 2.762 6.167 6.168M80.642 70.078c0 3.405 2.76 6.167 6.167 6.167 3.405 0 6.166-2.762 6.166-6.167 0-3.406-2.76-6.167-6.167-6.167s-6.168 2.762-6.168 6.168'/><path fill='#F37885' d='M49.263 99.49c0 8 6.356 14.196 14.196 14.196s14.196-6.195 14.196-14.195H49.263zM63.335 113.688c7.84 0 14.32-6.196 14.32-14.196H63.44'/><path fill='#78492F' d='M18.44 67.9V31.627s-11 1.995-11 7.98V61.37s4 6.53 11 6.53'/><path fill='#78492F' d='M74.44 9.49H14.62s2.54 13 8.888 13H.11s-2.72 14 18.863 14H74.44v-27zM108.44 31.626V20.562c0-5.985-4.88-10.07-8.21-11.07H71.21c-3.33 1-7.77 5.085-7.77 11.07v15.93h45V67.9s11-1.995 11-7.98V38.157s-5-6.53-11-6.53'/><path fill='#FEDBC8' d='M199.44 132.29c-42 0-44.34-36.73-44.164-43.028-1.398 0-11.287-1.224-11.287-9.62 0-13.293 11.45-11.544 11.45-11.544v-9.794l-.775-17.812h44.776v91.798z'/><path fill='#82A0D7' d='M183 72.296c0 3.284-2.663 5.946-5.947 5.946s-5.947-2.662-5.947-5.946 2.663-5.947 5.947-5.947S183 69.01 183 72.295'/><path fill='#F37885' d='M185.974 100.49c0 8 6.13 13.69 13.69 13.69s13.69-5.69 13.69-13.69h-27.38z'/><path fill='#FFC55D' d='M250.282 39.53S246.442 0 199.442 0v57.49h43.377l.466 42.736s.933 18.687 20.056 18.687M199.44 57.603V.233s-48.974-3.266-48.974 39.88c0 30.275 4.956 27.518 4.956 27.518l.32-10.494s16.66-2.798 16.66-14.925c5.863 7.695-1.96 15.393 27.04 15.393'/><path fill='#FEDBC8' d='M199.44 132.29c42 0 44.232-36.73 44.058-43.028 1.398 0 11.34-1.224 11.34-9.62 0-13.293-11.396-11.544-11.396-11.544v-9.794l.558-.813h-44.56v74.8z'/><path fill='#82A0D7' d='M216.232 72.296c0 3.284 2.663 5.946 5.947 5.946s5.946-2.662 5.946-5.946-2.663-5.947-5.947-5.947-5.948 2.662-5.948 5.946'/><path fill='#F37885' d='M199.44 114.18c7.563 0 13.913-5.688 13.913-13.688H199.44'/></svg>`

And some code, which renders this svg on my canvas, using fabricjs:

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(str, function(objects, options) {
  var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  obj.lockUniScaling = true;
  obj.scaleToWidth(200);
  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});
```

So i got this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

P.S. Background color is ok – canvas' color.

Help guys

Comment: Remove the working paths one at a time till you have something with only broken paths in it. You probably should then try to simplify the paths themselves so that you've something really simple as a testcase.

Comment: SVG parsing is still, ummm, off in Fabric. https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1055 Here's the list of what is known to be working and what isn't. There's also some good workarounds. Best thing is to post your SVG and let the team work on it/troubleshoot.

Comment: svg parsing is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so this svg works fine.
you probably used an old version of fabricjs when trying to parse it. that comes out is an old "a" command drawing bug.
if you copy paste this svg in the fabricjs.com/kitchensink  that is a general demo/tester you will see it working good.
so please download latest version of library and you should be fine